# Test schema.org ld+json content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, tdd

I have a view with the following content:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "<%= company.url %>",
  "contactPoint" : [{
    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "telephone" : "<%= company.phone_number %>",
    "contactType" : "customer service"
  }]
}
</script>
```

I'm stuck in my TDD workflow. What is the best way to test this kind of content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not test stuff like that.